# Icon spacing/padding on unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

As you can see from the picture, I removed the background light from the icons in the launcher. But now, it looks like there is too much space between the icons and the icons look small. Is there a way to reduce the spacing/padding between these icons. For example, the whole icon should fill the space used by the removed background light.
[image: too much spacing]